# Alternative of using try catch for an axios request when there is an error that returns nothing?

Tags: javascript, axios

At the moment, if I use

```
const response = await '$nuxt.axios.delete/account'; //pretend request
if(response) { 
  console.log('response', response); //logs if successful
  //response is {data: "", config:{transitional:{...}, status:204, statusText:""}
}
else { 
    console.log('error'); //will not log if there is an error
}
```

there is no response at all if there is an error. I want to check if it has been successful or not, so when it is successful I can then push the object into the array, so I won't have to make a new request to get the added piece of data.

I could use try and catch, which does return an error, but then I'd have to push the object into the array assuming it is successful, and only then delete it from the array if an error is caught. This seems a bit redundant.

Is there a way to get the response without using try catch or catch(error) ?

Comment: Syntax error !!

Comment: What do you mean? The request is successful on first deletion but on second deletion of the same modal, it will print DELETE 404 not found but in a completely different place, the else error doesn't log at all. I want to check first if it is successful and then remove it from the array. At this point, all I can do is save it, delete it from the array and if unsuccessful, then re add it?

Comment: Your code has a syntax error, please fix it

Comment: _"but then I'd have to push the object into the array assuming it is successful, and only then delete it from the array if an error is caught"_ - toggle a flag then which tells you whether you got something to add, and do the actually adding afterwards ...? `let flag_do_not_add = false; try { /*request*/ } catch(e) { flag_do_not_add = true; } if(!flag_do_not_add) { /*add to array*/ }`

Comment: @CBroe i think he is using something with graphql like response mechanism if `response.data === ' ' then it means the request failed

Comment: No I'm stupid big thank you! :D @CBroe if you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but then I'd have to push the object into the array assuming it is successful, and only then delete it from the array if an error is caught

You could instead toggle a flag then which tells you whether you got something to add, and do the actual adding afterwards.

```
let flag_do_not_add = false;
try {
  /*request*/
} catch(e) {
  flag_do_not_add = true;
}
if(!flag_do_not_add) {
  /*add to array*/
}
```